# point to the correct installation of bison

Tags: bash, path, installation, osx-mavericks, bison

I want to update the default installation of `bison` on my system (OSX 10.9).

I'd like to do this without using homebrew, as it's important for the update to "look native" to the OS for `make` and `configure`, etc.  I've gone ahead and DL'd from [this location](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bison/), and I installed, etc., but the installation is placed in `/usr/local/bin` rather than `/usr/bin/bison`.  `bison --version` yields the correct version, but `which bison` still yields `/usr/bin/bison`.  This is because I've simply made an alias in my bash profile to the location of `/usr/local/bin/bison`.  Can anyone help, or point me to a place where this information is covered?

Comment: I considered posting this to superuser, but I couldn't find any other posts on bison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Unix, tools are located via the PATH environment variable. The first location which contains the tool you are trying to run wins.

In this case, you should update your PATH like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

This will inject `/usr/local/bin` before the rest of the PATH entries and will ensure that this `bison` is picked up by all tools running in the shell.

I assume you are running bash of course, the syntax for setting the PATH variable will be different for other shells.

Comment: I'd already tried to make my path more specific than that, i.e., `export PATH=/usr/local/bin/bison:$PATH`, but it didn't work.  Could you elaborate on the reason for that?

Comment: You have bison in your path, just try `/usr/local/bin` - PATH contains directories rather than the tools themselves!

Comment: Right, its just that `/usr/local/bin` might contain other stuff i might not want to include. That was my thought, anyway.

Comment: hmmm...  this seems a bit strange to include the entire folder.  Can anyone suggest something that would be more specific to my bison installation?  I don't necessarily want to overwrite the version that is on my system, but that might be the easiest...